# What's wrong in this query on MySQL 5.7 using CASE?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use CASE on MySQ L5.7 on HeidiSQl,

I want to use CASE to call a table and use the CASE with the intervals 0, 1-100 and 100 or more.

But It's doesn't work

```
SELECT ventas.Ventas_Id AS ID, ventas.Ventas_Fecha AS fecha, ventas.Ventas_Neto AS neto
CASE  Ventas_Total
   WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total = 0 THEN 'C'
   WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total > 100 THEN 'S'
   WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total  < 100 THEN 'L'                       
END AS "Categoria"
FROM ventas
```

I have this error message

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE  ventas.Ventas_Total
>
> ```
>    WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total = 0 THEN 'C'
> ```
>
> at line 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two styles of `CASE` expression, and you are actually mixing syntax from both types.  Because you have an inequality in the `CASE` expression, you can only use this style:

```
CASE WHEN Ventas_Total = 0 THEN 'C'
     WHEN Ventas_Total > 100 THEN 'S'
     WHEN Ventas_Total < 100 THEN 'L'
END AS Categoria
```

The other style of `CASE` expression only works when you want to do only equality comparisons, e.g.

```
CASE Ventas_Total
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'C' END AS some_alias
```

Comment: @KenWhite The formatting is really off, so I didn't even see that `:-)`

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed the formatting. :-) Thought you might want to add that in your answer as an additional note.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, now it's working.

SELECT ventas.Ventas_Id AS ID, ventas.Ventas_Fecha AS fecha, ventas.Ventas_Neto AS neto,

```
    ventas.Ventas_Total AS Total
```

CASE  ventas.Ventas_Total

```
    WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total = 0 THEN 'C'


      WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total > 100 THEN 'S'

    WHEN ventas.Ventas_Total  < 100 THEN 'L'   END AS Categoria                



   FROM ventas
```